# Using XML column instead of Database table SQL

Tags: sql, xml

What are the pros and cons of using XML column instead of separate table?

Actually i am currently using a column with XML data type and i need to parse this column.Value in that column may be in following format

```
<user>
 <firstname></firstname>
 <lastname></lastname>
 <children>
   <child1>abc</child1>
   <child2>pqr</child2>
   <child3>lmn</child3>
 </children>
</user>
```

I need to iterate through the Childern node and find out the three child node values using SQL query.Is that possible using query?

Comment: Do you want to say that you want to use XML documents?

Comment: does this refer to MS SQL Server XML column data type?

Comment: An XML column must be **in a database table** .... so what exactly are you trying to do / to achieve with this?? What's wrong with having a table??

Comment: @devio : yes this is related to MS SQL Server XML column data type.Actually I have come across a situation where i need to decide whether i should use a this XML column or entirely different table for this.

Comment: Better create a "children" table with FK references a parent(user) table. I think that's what you need. In case if you need to have something like RL father/mother relationship then a many-to-many table with references to parent table and to children table. I guess so.

Comment: yes that is definitely a solution.But is there any way we can select a child nodes with unknown names as those nodes are generated dynamically.And i need to select their respective values it using sql query.thanks in advance.

Comment: well if you have a parent name  or id then yes of course. `select c.name from children c inner join family f on c.id=f.child_id inner join user u on u.id=f.parent_id where u.name='yourparentname'` or `u.id=` instead in `where`. family is the many-to-many with references to parent_id in users table and to child_id in children table. should be something like that. if i got you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on two SQL Server/XML projects, and from this experience my opinion *may* be a *bit* biased.

In the first case, SQL Server 2005 had trouble [parsing datetimes with time zone information](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/handling-xsd-datetime-sql-server-2005/) (because 2005 was generally not time zone aware). In that project, XML was only used for data transfer between an application and a web service where each outgoing and incoming XML message needed to be logged in the database.

In the second case, the data was largely stored in XML, and this approach showed a couple of problems SQL Server (2008) has/had with XML:

- while you can store XML in a column (both typed and untyped), you cannot define the usual constraints in XML: uniqueness, checks, foreign keys
- lack of constraints implicitly means data consistency in XML is not guaranteed
- CRUD always means you always need to write XQuery statements to retrieve the records you operate on
- processing data in .Net requires the XML data to be serialized to and from .Net proxy classes (xsd.exe)
- altering XML schemas already referenced by table columns is a major headache, as I [described on my blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/altering-xml-schema-collections/).
- if your source XML contains an encoding attribute in the xml header, SQL Server will [refuse to process the XML](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/retrieving-xml-data-in-sql-server-2005/) altogether.

If you need to process XML data in SQL, you should provide an Import XML table, and process its contents into regular relational tables. You're free to decide you implement this in .Net or TSQL.